# The .toISOString() results into a date ahead of the current date-Js

Tags: javascript, date

I just tried converting the current date into a ISOstring format:

```
(new Date()).toISOString();
```

and it resulted into `"2015-06-24T05:28:51.549Z"` instead `"2015-06-23T05:28:51.549Z"`
Anyone has any ideas why would it do that, or how to avoid getting date in string format ahead of the current date??

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp

Comment: Please @Zeeshan - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) is a better resource

Comment: Are you (or your os settings) living in yesterday? We've got the 24th.

Comment: @Bergi, I did not mark it a true duplicate since it is one whole day ahead of the expected date. Either user1234 did not post the correct examples or there is something else going on. I believe that one has to live in Tuvalu to be a whole day behind

Comment: @mplungjan: You're right, even in Tuvalu it's not 5:28. Feel free to reopen, but I feel this question is "too localised" or "not reproducable" in the current format anyway.

Comment: I just pasted the link so the asker could delete or elaborate. We can re-open if it turns out that there is a real issue :)